# ORA-01850 Error on TO_NUM(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE function

Tags: plsql

I'm running into this "ORA-01850" error on only the LOGIN_TIME portion of my query. I believe this is because some people on my team are forgetting to logout at the end of their shift and thus their login time is exceeding 24 hours on some of those data fields (which it shouldn't).

So basically what I want my query to do is; read the login time and if it exceeds 24 hours then reduce that time back down to 24 hours, so that it can then be converted into seconds.

I think that will correct the error? But how do I even do that?

```
SELECT
CALL_DATE as "Date"
, TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CALL_TIME,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss'))/86400 as "Time"
, AGENT_GROUP as "Agent Group"
, AGENT_NAME as "Agent Name"
, STATE as "State"
, REASON_CODE as "Reason Code"
, TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LOGIN_TIME,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss'))/86400 as "Login Time"
, TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(READY_TIME,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss'))/86400 as "Ready Time"
, TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(NOT_READY_TIME,'hh24:mi:ss'),'sssss'))/86400 as "Not Ready Time"

FROM DB.AGENT_DETAILS

WHERE 
AGENT_GROUP in ('Sales')
and TRUNC(CALL_DATE) BETWEEN '01-January-2017' and TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `CALL_TIME`, `LOGIN_TIME`, `READY_TIME` and `NOT_READY_TIME`? If they are VARCHAR2s, `ORA-01850 hour must be between 0 and 23` implies that at least one row starts with the number 24 or greater; if they are DATEs, it means you're getting an implicit conversion problem (i.e. if they are DATEs already, you should not call TO_DATE on them).

Comment: If they are DATEs already, an alternative way to get what you need is `(call_time-trunc(call_time))*86400` which removes the need for so many datatype conversions.

Comment: Yes, they are VARCHAR2. And yes it's the "ORA-01850 hour must be between 0 and 23 hour" error. So how do I add a clause to convert the times that are greater back down to 24? That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: (call_time-trunc(call_time))*86400 ....does not work for me. But it wouldn't since it's VARCHAR2 correct?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your data is stored in VARCHAR2s, and they are using a non-standard method to store intervals greater than a day. Therefore, we need to do a little bit of string manipulation to get them into a format that can be consumed by a builtin Oracle function.

One such Oracle function that can help is TO_DSINTERVAL, which can optionally accept an ISO interval expressed in hours, minutes, and seconds - but it must look like `PT24H03M55S`.

Here is an example:

```
with q1 as (
  /*here is the source data*/
  select '24:03:45' as t from dual
), q2 as (
  /*parse and convert to iso interval format*/
  select 'PT' || substr(t,1,2) || 'H'
              || substr(t,4,2) || 'M'
              || substr(t,7,2) || 'S'
  as iso from q1
), q3 as (
  /*convert to an Oracle Day-To-Second Interval*/
  select to_dsinterval(iso) i from q2
)
  /*convert interval to whole number of seconds*/
select trunc((i + sysdate - sysdate) * 86400) as sssss from q3;

86625
```